# Nested SQL to LINQ in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I've a nested sql select statement which is as following:

```
select * from
(
select amount_txt + ' ' + ingredient_txt as c1, * from TABLE_A
where  part_nbr in (
select part_nbr from TABLE_B
where version_nbr = (
select version_nbr from TABLE_C
where version_guid = '84376053-0ece-4305-835f-cfe9261ce33f')
)
) as t
where c1   = '1 pound boneless skinless chicken breast, cut into 1/4-inch slices'
```

This is what i've tried. But i am not getting it right

```
Dim version = dataContext.TABLE_C.Where(Function(x) x.version_guid = version_guid).SingleOrDefault()
Dim Part = dataContext.TABLE_B.Where(Function(x) x.version_nbr = version.recipe_version_nbr).ToList()                
Dim result = dataContext.TABLE_A.Where(Function(x) Part.Contains(x.part_nbr)).ToList()
```

The code i've tried is incomplete as i am not able to figure out how to write in linq. I am using VB.Net. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Suyog

Comment: As soon as you use `ToList` you're no longer in LINQ to SQL. Next method will be evaluated using LINQ to Objects.

Comment: What is "not right"? What is `c1`? And what flavor of LINQ is this?